# React Native Form Submit

Tags: javascript, react-native

I would like to submit information to my email from my app when I press a button. Is there a form option like in HTML? Can you insert HTML in react native? Sorry if this is terrible question I'm still learning a lot of it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Linking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html).

`Linking.openURL('mailto:youremail@gmail.com?subject=hello&body=body')`

Example

```
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => {
    Linking.openURL('mailto: youremail@gmail.com?subject=hello&body=body');
    }}
    <Text>youremail@gmail.com</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Change subject and body to yours in example.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `TextInput` component - there are definitely existing ways in react-native to submit information like as a form in html. There are even some libraries that help you do it!

Comment: I cant find a way to use 'mailto:test@example.com' in TextInput. I'll look into other libraries :)